# Как лучше организовать таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, yii2

Есть таблица с данными файлов (путь, оригинальное имя, дата создания и т.п.). И есть разные связи которые должны ссылаться на эти файлы. Например файл привязанный к статье или файл привязанный к конкурсу (это разные таблицы). Раньше такая связь была только одна и в таблице файлов была ссылка на соответствующую таблицу (у статьи или конкурса может быть несколько файлов). Но сейчас, когда связей стало несколько надо как-то по другому организовать. Единственный вариант который я вижу (если конечно не перекопировать для каждой связи всю структуру таблицы файлов) это сделать для каждой связи таблицу вида `ArticleFile(article_id, file_id)` и отдельную таблицу файлов `File(id, path, original_name, created_at...)`. Но как это организовать в Yii2? Немного неудобно было бы с этим делом обращаться если надо будет сначала получить все связи из таблицы ArticleFile, потом подгрузить к ним сами данные из таблицы File.... И добавлять/редактировать/удалять тоже не кайф. Возможно ли это как-то через наследование организовать? Или еще как-то...

upd. Или еще идея, пожалуй наиболее простая - оставить ссылку прямо в таблице файлов, типа `File(id, ref_id, path...)`, но снять с нее FK и привязывать таким образом файл к любой таблице. Да теряется контроль на уровне БД, да костыль, зато так реально просто очень выйдет.

Comment: Можно сделать так называемый "сервисный слой" который можно использовать и расширять наследованием при необходимости. Пример можно посмотреть тут http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/105/services-and-controllers

Comment: @AlexMaxTM ох уж эти репозитории, сервисы и прочая кододрочня. Мне это в Java на Spring хватило. Разводить это все в пыхе - не торт. К тому же тут уже есть орм и чистый скл не понадобится.

Comment: В конце концов оказалось что лучше будет скопировать всю структуру, тем более что там (для файлов конкурса) добавились/удалились некоторые поля.

Answer (score 0):

А чем Вам не нравится Вами же описанный способ? Мы везде его используем.
С правильно настроенными fk никаких проблем нет, а для простоты редактирования можно использовать поведение - https://github.com/voskobovich/yii2-linker-behavior 
Связь:

```
`public function getFiles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(
        File::className(),
        ['id' => 'file_id']
    )->viaTable(
        ArticleFile::tableName(),
        ['article_id' => 'id']
    );
}
```

`

Использование:

```
`foreach($article->files as $file) {
 print Html::img($file->getPublicUrl())
}`
```